# wp_enqueuescript won't load in footer even with true value set?

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

Below is my code for enqueue my scripts and css. I am trying to get the JavaScripts to load in the footer of my site, but when I view source I see them loading in the header. I suppose the "true" value isn't working properly or I have sequenced the code incorrectly?

```
// Enque CSS and JavaScript
if (!is_admin()) {

// CSS Reset
wp_register_style( 'reset', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/reset.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'reset' );

// 960 GS
wp_register_style( 'grid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/960.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'grid' );

// Style
wp_register_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );

// jQuery
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery',("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"), true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

// jQuery UI
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_register_script('jquery-ui-core',("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"), true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');

// Easy Slider
wp_register_script('easy-slider',get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/js/easySlider1.7.js", true);
wp_enqueue_script('easy-slider');

// Scripts
wp_register_script('myscript',get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/js/scripts.js", true);
wp_enqueue_script('myscript');

// Facebook API
wp_register_script('facebook-loader',("http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Loader"), true);
wp_enqueue_script('facebook-loader');
wp_register_script('facebook-sharer',("http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share"), true);
wp_enqueue_script('facebook-sharer');

// Twitter API
wp_register_script('twitter',("//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"), true);
wp_enqueue_script('twitter');

}
```

Comment: What hook are you using for this? You should be using `wp_enqueue_scripts` for both CSS and JS and you can ditch the `is_admin` check if you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need top put it into an actual function and then call the function via an action, but to answer your question.

```
wp_register_script('easy-slider',get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/js/easySlider1.7.js", true);
```

Your setting the third parameter to `true` but that param is for the `$deps` (dependency). The footer is the 5th parameter called `$in_footer`.

So it should be:

```
 wp_register_script('easy-slider',get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/js/easySlider1.7.js", '', '', true);
```

Reference:

```
 wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```